# Is it possible to have a singleton instance created from a factory

Tags: java, singleton, factory

Recently I have learned of the factory and singleton design patterns and would like to implement them together. The issue I am having is that the `getInstance` method defined in a singleton class has to be static, so how can I declare this method in an interface? Java 1.8 has allowed for static methods within interfaces *however* this insists that a method body is implemented within the actual interface - this immediately subtracts from the efficacy of using the singleton with a factory.

For example:

```
// Logger.java (interface)
public interface Logger {

    public Logger getInstance();
    public static void log(String message);

}
```

produces an error when implemented like:

```
// File implementation of Logger (also a database implementation)
public class FileLogger implements Logger {

    private static FileLogger instance;

    private FileLogger() {
    }

    @Override
    public static Logger getInstance() {
        synchronized (FileLogger.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new FileLogger();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(new Date() + " " + message);
    }

}
```

from a factory like:

```
// Factory pattern to create differing types of logger
public class LoggerFactory {

    private LoggerFactory() {

    }

    public static Logger getLogger(LoggerType loggerType) {
        Logger logger;

        switch (loggerType) {
            case DATABASE:
                logger = DatabaseLogger.getInstance();
                break;
            default:
                logger = FileLogger.getInstance();
        }
        return logger;
    }

    public enum LoggerType {
        DATABASE, FILE;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this explains my predicament. The error I am getting is `missing method body`

Are there any ways to solve this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `static` interface method.

Comment: Why would you need the `static` method on the interface? You access static methods through their type directly, so you already know if it has a `getInstance` method. You could instead place the `getInstance` method as an `abstract` method on the `LoggerType` enum, that would eliminate your switch statement.

Comment: Removing the definition from the interface completely fixed my issue. I was thinking you could only implement methods defined in the interface? Anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your question but you could do something like this to have a factory "produce" singletons.

What you are looking for with a factory is usually an instance of a particular interface. Whether it is a singleton or not is irrelevant, from the perspective of the caller of the factory method. So I'd define an interface as so:

```
public interface InterestingInterface {
    public void print(); // my interesting method that I need all 
                         // "products to implement"
}
```

And then my classes that implements the interface could be singletons or not depending on their purpose, so:

```
public class SingletonA implements InterestingInterface {

    private static SingletonA instance = null;

    private SingletonA(){}

    public static SingletonA getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonA();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am A");
    }
}

class SingletonB implements InterestingInterface {
    private static SingletonB instance = null;

    private SingletonB(){}

    public static SingletonB getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonB();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am B");
    }
}

public class C implements InterestingInterface {
    @override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am C");
    }
}
```

The responsibility of the factory is to know which implementing class to instantiate and how to do it. In this case it could look like this:

```
public class SingletonFactory {
    public static InterestingInterface produce(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case 1:
                return SingletonA.getInstance();
            case 2:
                return SingletonB.getInstance();
            case 3:
                return new C();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

With this your factory provides you with the correct implementation of an interface depending on your input (could be the type class you used in your question rather than ints) and some of the implementations (or all if you wish) can be singletons.